# npm start not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

My `package.json` file is as below

```
{
  "name": "dev",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-native": "0.49.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "21.2.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "21.2.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-beta.5"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

When I run `npm start` it gets stuck on **Loading dependency graph, done.** How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you configured the dev settings in emulator?

Answer (score 2):

`npm start` only works for expo projects, if you've created your project using `react-native init` 
You should run your project using either `react-native run-ios` or `react-native run-android`

If you're sure you're using expo for your project I would suggest to remove the `node_modules` folder and running `npm install` again.

Answer (score 0):

If you built your app using `react-native init` or if it is an app that has been "ejected" from Expo, then this behavior is normal.  Once you have npm started, open another terminal window and run either `react-native run-ios` or `react-native run-android`.  That should launch the appropriate app for you.

The [Getting Started Guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) can walk you through the various ways of starting a react native app.  You should follow the tab labeled "Building Projects with Native Code."